# IP assignment in a /28 block

Tags: ip, routing, subnet

Need help on setting up firewall router.  My config is as below:

Public static network ID: x.x.x.48/28
gateway: x.x.x.49
available IP for the hosts: x.x.x.52 to 62

gw_eth0 <--> fw_eth0 - fw_eth1 <--> dmz_switch

Four servers are connected on dmz_switch (say s1, s2, s3, s4) all have to use public static IP address from the above block.

Any recommendation on IP assignment and route setup?  Do I need to subnet the above block further or simply use /32 netmask and point-to-point static routes in the above setup?

Answer (score 2):

Usually you set up a non-routable network in DMZ (say 172.16.0.0/24), assign an IP address to each host in that network and establish a full NAT between public IP addresses and DMZ addresses in the firewall configuration.

Comment: Yes, or setup the firewall in transparent mode if possible.

Answer (score 0):

How many devices are in the above picture, and what kind of devices?  Here is a private scheme, one of which matches your public scheme

```
Network           Net Broadcast     CIDR Mask              UsableHosts 
192.168.1.0       192.168.1.15      28   255.255.255.240   14          
192.168.1.16      192.168.1.31      28   255.255.255.240   14          
192.168.1.32      192.168.1.47      28   255.255.255.240   14          
192.168.1.48      192.168.1.63      28   255.255.255.240   14
```

Here is the /28 in two parts

```
Network           Net Broadcast     CIDR Mask              UsableHosts 
192.168.1.48      192.168.1.55      29   255.255.255.248   6
192.168.1.56      192.168.1.63      29   255.255.255.248   6
```

Without more info...

The above tables generated from [My Subnet Planner](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3789524#post3789524)